# Basic insulation level for a 22 kV system

Tags: basic, insulation, level

In the lab we tested a surge arrestor bracket for a 22 kV system with a 1.2/50 impulse. It was found that U10 for the bracket is 102 kV. I found this table for IEC standard of a 22 kV system
[image]

I read up about Basic Insulation Levels and to my understanding is that the system from the table for 22 kV should be able to handle 125 kV surge. Which means that the arrestor bracket must have a BIL lower than that in order to absorb the surge. Am I correct ?, or can someone help me understand this more clearly ?, thanks

Comment: Sounds very high. Does that voltage refer to your test source with any impedance in series to the actual arrester? If it won't clamp until 100+ kV, the lightning will have an almost free path?

Comment: By clamp do you mean breakdown ? or flashover of the bracket ?

Comment: By clamp do you mean breakdown ? or flashover of the bracket ?, I calculated U10 from U50 which was 106.49 kV using, U10 = U50(1-1.3s) where s = 0.03. We used a Marx generator which I think had some front time resistors in series

Comment: Yes, breakdown. Your front is faster than "mine" but the holding versus clamping/breakdown ratio still sounds very high. Where did you get U10 and U50 from?

Comment: U50 was found using the up/down test in the experiment. U10 was found using U50 from this formula, U10 = U50(1-1.3s). I used s = 0.03

Comment: That formula sounds suspicious as you go faster and faster. At high speed/short front, your loop inductance will play a major role.

Comment: I got that formula from the IEC document. They say "s" is the standard deviation of the disruptive discharge voltage. They also say " For dry tests on air insulation, without any
other insulation involved, the per-unit value s = 0,03 can be used". Would that value apply to my situation also ?

Comment: Interesting. Did you get any curves from the arrester manufacturer?

Comment: No, but the arrester is a varistar ultrasil. It's a Zno type. Its a 10kA class 1. Also would the protection ratio be 125 kV/102 kV ?

Comment: I think we also only tested the arrester mounting bracket. Could that maybe explain the high breakdown voltage ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58377/discussion-between-winny-and-deadshot).

Comment: Thanks for your help. So since the breakdown voltage is less than 125 kV for the bracket, then it has failed the test for minimum insulation right ?, seems odd

Comment: Yes, for sure but it's not stange. I doubt you can get a factor of ~5 times the voltage by increasing the front time in the fist place and secondly transfer it to just the bracket.